# Google Cloud Speech API- Permission Error

Tags: google-cloud-speech

The API is already enabled in console still getting this error.

```
data:{  
   error:{  
      code:403,
      message:'Cloud Speech API has not been used in project ************ before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/overview?project=************ then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.',
      status:'PERMISSION_DENIED',
      details:[  
         Array
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify how are you doing your request, as well if you did the [Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-protocol#before_you_begin) steps already, regarding the environment variable?

Comment: I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries) documentation and have set the env variable properly as well.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Keep in mind that the environment variable should be set every time you open a CLI.

Comment: NodeJS and yes I'm keeping it in mind.

Comment: I disabled the API in the account and then enabled it again.And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just not to leave the question unanswered. According the comment on Nov 21st, disabling and enabling the API solved the issue.